# Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: java, ios, download

I am trying to download multiple files from another server using Spring RestTemplate on click of a button in JSF UI screen. Files get downloaded properly(means REST service working perfectly fine). While downloading each files from Rest service, I need to put them in a ZIP file. Once all the files gets downloaded then user has to see just 1 zip file in browser footer as the file being downloaded.

But I am getting `Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine`

My sample code is as below:

```java
public void downLoadFile() throws IOException {
    String fileNameToDownload;
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
    ec.responseReset();
    String fileName = "MyDownloadFile.zip";
    ec.setResponseContentType("application/zip");
    ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
    OutputStream out = ec.getResponseOutputStream();
    zos = new ZipOutputStream(out);

    Iterator<String> it = fileNamesList.iterator();

    //Iterate through all fileNames and download each file from REST service
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        fileNameToDownload = (String) it.next();
        byte bytes[] = new byte[2048];

        //Makes REST WS call to get document content in byte[] and convert to InputStream
        MyResponseObject myResponseObject = SpringRestService.getDocumentByDocumentName(fileNameToDownload);
        byte[] fileBytes = myResponseObject.getFileContent();
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileBytes);

        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileNameToDownload));
        int numBytesRead = is.read(bytes);
        while (numBytesRead > 0) {
            zos.write(bytes, 0, numBytesRead);
            numBytesRead = is.read(bytes);
        }
        is.close();
    }
    zos.closeEntry();

    zos.flush();
    out.flush();

    zos.close();
    out.close();

    ec.getResponseOutputStream().flush();
    ec.getResponseOutputStream().close();
    fc.responseComplete();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `zos.closeEntry()` be inside the while loop?

Comment: It's possible that you're timing out.

Comment: Did anyone get a solution to this problem?